# Incorrect form of table

Tags: tables

I have the following table which I cam up with in order to response to the examiner's report for my thesis. The problem here is that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\huge Response to Examiners’ Reports}

\vspace{5em}
\begin{tabular}{| L{4cm} | L{8cm} |}
\hline
Candidate Name &
Shahrina Ismail \\
\hline
Thesis Title & Perfect Triangles : Rational points on Elliptic Curves \\
\hline
School & School of Mathematics \& Physics, University of Queensland \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}


\vspace{3em}
\begin{tabular}{| L{8cm} | L{8cm} | L{3cm} |}
\hline
Examiner's comment &
Response & Page\\
\hline
knowledge in & requirement in & P1L2\\
\hline
standardized & standardised & P1L2\\
\hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**1. The first table:** how to increase the height of the rows. My rows look crowded.

**2. The second table** is not showing up the third column, not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've minimized your table to the necessary details. For more spacing I used `\arraystretch`. And your second  question has a simple answer too: Your table was too wide for the side (actually the third column printed, but outside of the page). To achieve a better look I just turned those tables into `tabularx` as you already used that package.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\huge Response to Examiners’ Reports}

\vspace{5em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| L{5cm} | X |}
\hline
Candidate Name &
Shahrina Ismail \\
\hline
Thesis Title & Perfect Triangles : Rational points on Elliptic Curves \\
\hline
School & School of Mathematics \& Physics, University of Queensland \\
\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}

\vspace{3em}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X | L{3cm} |}
\hline
Examiner's comment &
Response & Page\\
\hline
knowledge in & requirement in & P1L2\\
\hline
standardized & standardised & P1L2\\
\hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

Probably it would be better, if you would consider using `booktabs` (which you already include). That would look like this:

[image: table 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\huge Response to Examiners’ Reports}

\vspace{5em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L{5cm} X}
\toprule
Candidate Name &
Shahrina Ismail \\
\midrule
Thesis Title & Perfect Triangles : Rational points on Elliptic Curves \\
\midrule
School & School of Mathematics \& Physics, University of Queensland \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

\vspace{3em}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X L{3cm}}
\toprule
Examiner's comment &
Response & Page\\
\midrule
knowledge in & requirement in & P1L2\\
standardized & standardised & P1L2\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx so much for explaining this to me. I have one concern though. There's like plenty of space on the right hand side and left hand side of the page. I need more space for the column "examiner's comment" and "response".  How do I play around with "X" ?

Comment: @shahrinaismail You cannot play around with it (that's the sense of X, determining the correct size of the column). You can just switch back to your `L` column, but then you have to consider that a page has some dimensions.